# How to execute a scheduled task with “schtasks” without opening a new command line window using C# process?

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a scheduled task from C# without opening a new command line window, using the following code without any success (it prompts a window every time I use it)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {

                    Process p1 = new Process();
                    p1.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe";
                    p1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                    p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/run /tn CCleaner";
                    p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    p1.Start();
                    p1.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }



            }
        }
    }
```

How could I solve this problem ?

Thank you so much for your attention

Comment: Are you sure the command line window you're seeing come up isn't your own application's? It's possible you may want to look into running a background service instead.

Comment: Thanks Dasanko, That was it!!! I was seeing my own app. I made a simple test using a Windows Form Application to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library that provides access to Task Scheduler API.

For example using http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

```
using (var ts = new TaskService())
{
    Task task = ts.GetTask("My task");                
    task.Run();                
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using that library to create the scheduled task, but I need to run it on demand, and unfortunately this library doesn't have that functionality.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoCarmonaOrtega , are you using this specific libary? I've added a code block that can be used to run a task. Just keep in mind that you might need UAC elevation for your application to run some of the scheduled tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Yes, I was using this specific library, but I didn't know how to run a task. I checked the documentation and I didn't found anything about it. I am writing a program to bypass the UAC prompt following this tutorial http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html. So far, this library is going to be the way to go. Thank you!!! By the way, do you know if there is a method in this library to determinate the existence of a task?

Comment: @CarlosEduardoCarmonaOrtega, I think GetTask will return null if task does not exist or you don't have access to it.